# Is there any type-safe API for structured streaming window operations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, apache-spark-dataset

**TL;DR:** Is there a type-safe equivalent to the following example

```scala
import spark.implicits._

val words = ... // streaming DataSet of schema: case class Record(timestamp: Timestamp, word: String)

// Group the data by window and word and compute the count of each group
val windowedCounts = words
    .withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes")
    .groupBy(
        window($"timestamp", "10 minutes", "5 minutes"),
        $"word")
    .count()
```

---

I really like the type-safe API of Spark, avoiding any typos in column names.
I know the [Aggregator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Aggregator.html) class and how to build my own aggregators.

However I don't see how I can apply the `withWatermark` and build the `window` column in a type-safe way ?

Do you know if any API or library already exists ? If not, do you see any good solution ?

Currently, my best solution is to call a `WindowOperator` transforming a `Dataset[REC]` to a `Dataset[TimeWindowed[REC]]` with something like:

```scala
 case class TimeWindowed[REC](data: REC, timeWindow: TimeWindow)
 case class TimeWindow(start: java.sql.Timestamp, end: java.sql.Timestamp)
```

I am thinking of changing this to something like `Dataset[(TimeWindow, REC)]`, which can be more idiomatic, compared to the returned type of the `...byKey` functions family (`Dataset[(K, REC)]`). But I don't manage to find a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spark 3, there is a utility method for you to construct the interval string safely (as in, avoiding any typos):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.IntervalUtils
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal
val zeroSec = Decimal(0, Decimal.MAX_LONG_DIGITS, 6)
IntervalUtils.makeInterval(years = 0, months = 0, weeks = 0, days = 0, hours = 0, mins = 10, secs = zeroSec).toString
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately I am stuck with Spark 2.4.+.